# plot() function causes Scilab to freeze in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, plot, scilab

Scilab 5.3.3 freezes whenever I try to run the plot() function in Ubuntu 11.10.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in the mesa package of Ubuntu. Ubuntu people introduced a patch which breaks mesa (Debian does not have the bug).

See:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/965798

https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=566

A fix is to update Ubuntu to the latest release.